# bing map control doesn't respect div

Tags: html, ajax, bing-maps

From this page http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#CreateMap1 I was able to create a map.
This is the html code:

```
<div class="fluid-row" style="height:300px;">
<div class="span12">
    <div id="prdmap" class="map">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
var map = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('prdmap'), {
        credentials: 'api_key',
        enableSearchLogo: false,
        enableClickableLogo: false
    });
    map.setView({mapTypeId : Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road});
});
```

But when the map loads it takes all the screen, not the height and with of its container.
Is this possible to take the height and width of the container div?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the position parameter solved my problem.

```
<div id="prdmap" style="position:absolute; width:400px; height:400px;></div>
```

Comment: Using relative positioning will have the same effect without taking the div out of the flow of the document.

Comment: I was able to use relative as well. I do not have to assign dimensions in the API call.  The problem is directly tied to the position rule on the div. What is odd, is this was working is for months.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a width and height specified(or inherited) on the container element, the map will take it.  The code you posted show nothing about the actual width and height of `prdmap`.  There could be CSS styles regarding width and height defined for the id `prdmap`, the class `map`, or for a `<div>` under class `span12` etc... you get the idea.  Examine your html source to see why the map is talking up the whole screen.  Also try defining an explicit width and height inline if possible:

```
        <div id='prdmap' style="width:500px; height:500px">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the height and width while creating the map.

```
  map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('prdmap'), {
    credentials: 'api_key',
    enableSearchLogo: false,
    enableClickableLogo: false,
    width:500,
    height:500
});
```